# Using HyperlinkedModelSerializer can we make some fields(ForeignKey field) without url, only id(if doesn't have detail-view)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework. In serializer I used HyperlinkedModelSerializer, but there are some foreign key fields with detail-view so it can be rendered as url, but some of them don't, it gives me the following error:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "unit-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field
```

So how to fix it?

**serializers.py**

```
class MaterialSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Material
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'location', 'category', 'unit', 'type', 'price',)
```

**views.py**

```
class MaterialViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Material.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MaterialSerializer
```

**models.py**

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='material', max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', user_views.UserViewSet, 'users') 
router.register('profiles', profile_views.ProfileViewSet, 'profile') 
router.register('location', LocationViewSet, 'location') 
router.register('category', CategoryViewSet) 
router.register('materials', MaterialViewSet) 
router.register('supplier', SupplierViewSet) 
router.register('transaction', TransactionViewSet) 

urlpatterns = [
     path('v1/', include(router.urls)), 
    ]
```

So in my API, I want to be my foreign key fields 'location' and 'category' with URL and 'unit' field only id

Comment: can you post your urls.py file

Comment: router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', user_views.UserViewSet, 'users')
router.register('profiles', profile_views.ProfileViewSet, 'profile')
router.register('location', LocationViewSet, 'location')
router.register('category', CategoryViewSet)
router.register('materials', MaterialViewSet)
router.register('supplier', SupplierViewSet)
router.register('transaction', TransactionViewSet)
urlpatterns = [path('v1/', include(router.urls)),
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "unit-detail".` you are seeing because in your `MaterialSerializers.py`
you are using `unit` as a field and there is no url for unit .

## Solution :

add a new view `UnitViewset`

## serializers.py

```
class UnitSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = "__all__"
```

## views.py

```
class UnitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Unit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitSerializer
```

## urls.py

```
router.register('units',UnitViewSet)
```

edit in your `models.py`

if you expecting blank values in Foreignkey fields for Material model add `blank=True`

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(default='material',blank=True, max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0,blank=True,  null=True)
```

Comment: An upvote would be greatly appreciated and accept if your problem solved